# aws ec2 import-image via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm searching for the Terraform equivalent of "aws ec2 import-image --description "Windows 2008 OVA" --license-type  --disk-containers file://containers.json" but cannot find a matching resource command in the documentation.

The purpose is to lift an OVA image out of S3 and covert to AMI so it can be used to launch EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in packer where you can create OVA by a builder and upload it to S3 and then create an AMI. Once you have the AMI, you can inject into your terraform script to launch it.

https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/amazon-import.html

Comment: So there isn't any way to do this without using Packer too?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5998

Right now terraform not supporting for ec2 image import